# Renaming tag `graphs` to `graph-theory`

Tags: discussion, tags

I suggest that we rename the tag [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) to [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) for the following reasons:

1. The word [`graphs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphs) is ambiguous.
2. [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) looks more professional.

The tag graph might have legitimate uses, but the question tagged with graphs so far are questions in graph theory.

Please express you agreement/disagreement with the suggested change by voting on the question. You can take back or change your vote in case you thought that votes on the question were not meant to be for/against the suggestion.

Comment: How would you tag questions about graph algorithms? Graph theory is, for me, the mathematical studies of graphs. I don't see how that applies to most questions we have with [tag:graphs].

Comment: @Raphael, by [tag:algorithms] and [tag:graph-theory] tags. Graph theory is not 
*just* the mathematical study of the graphs, see the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) or the standard textbooks on the topic like "Intro. to Graph Theory" by D.B. West or by J. Bondy. Graph algorithms is a large part of graph theory.

Comment: [I agree](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/135/about-the-tag-graph/136#136), and favor making a synonym [tag:graphs] → [tag:graph-theory].

Comment: We've got quite a few new questions in these tags, do you still think they should be made synonyms?

Comment: @Gilles, yes, I think the points still apply.

Comment: @Gilles: Is the proposed synonym a good idea, given that graphs is ambiguous? Do we expect questions about other graphs than those with nodes and edges?

Comment: the other meaning can be stated more explicitly like function-graphs and graphics so they are not ambiguous.

Comment: Are you serious about “[graph-theory] looks more professional”?  [graphs] does look equally professional to me, although I completely agree with you that [graphs] can mean graphs of functions and therefore graphs as in graph theory should be tagged as graph-theory.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, I felt so, but it might be just my personal bias.

Comment: @Raphael Just thinking out loud... hould we go ahead and make a decision on this? Are we going to get ride of graphs and use graph-theory, then?

Comment: @Patrick87: We could, but the "voting" is not very clear (+2/-1 vs +0/-2), igboring the question itself; apparently not many people care (which we can use as indicator that most are fine with either decision?). Any opposition to the mods deciding?

Comment: @Raphael, the number of votes on the question shows quite well that people care and have expressed their view about changing the tag on these questions to [tag:graph-theory]. The reason I personally haven't voted on the answers is that as I said before I don't have an opinion on keeping or removing the [tag:graphs] tag, that is a side issue. Others might have similar opinions.

Comment: @Kaveh: Your question text does not talk about retagging, but about "renaming" [tag:graphs] to [tag:graph-theory]. If that is supposed to mean anything (there is no such function for non-staff) then I have to read it as "Get rid of [tag:graphs]". This is equivalent to Patrick's answer which has barely been voted on, which supports my concern that votes on the question can not be considered *votes* on the matter.

Comment: @Raphael, renaming the tag doesn't mean getting rid of the tag forever. I think I have replied to your concern before and no one seems to have changed their vote since the edit last week.

Comment: @Kaveh: That's a weak argument; based on general meta activity, I doubt that most voters have even noted the edit.

Comment: @Raphael, these votes don't need much activity. It seems to me that you simply don't like it and are looking for excuses.

Comment: @Kaveh: That's your assumption; no need to become hostile. I may be overruled in this, but you won't convince me that votes on this question *provably* reflect the community's wishes. a) Your question has never stated a clear proposal; it is unclear what you think "renaming" a tag means. In fact, at least Tsuyoshi and me read it differently. b) The question did not state how votes would be interpreted from the beginning, and you can not assume the later edit was read and acted upon by all voters. Therefore, I consider only the votes on answers to hold meaning, and those are inconclusive.

Comment: @Raphael, there is no hostility, but I should say I am becoming quite frustrated by this discussion. If the post was not clear you should have asked for a clarification when I posted the question not now! No one seemed to have a problem with what I posted. If you disagreed with what my suggestion about editing the question and making it clear that the votes count for/against the suggestion then you should objected last week, not now after a week. Both of your answers have negative vote and the suggestion in the question is +7. But I personally don't care what you think counts here anymore.

Comment: Since graph-algorithm is a tag synonym of graphs, I can't see any reason why graph-theory is not.

Comment: Voting on the question is not a good way to reflect agreement or disagreement with the proposal because an upvote can also mean “that's a good question” and it doesn't leave room for “I propose a third option”. If there had been an answer in support with a frankly positive score, this might have been settled quickly. As it is, we're debating it [again](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/should-we-merge-graphs-with-graph-theory) 6 years later.

Comment: Seriously @Gilles, "this horse is dead". My comment is, let's see, from 6 years ago! :) (I don't have anything to add to what I have already written above.)

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw a possibility into the mix. Why not keep [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) and lose [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs)? I don't personally have any hang-ups about using [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) and [algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) for algorithms about graphs, or [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) and [data-structures](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures) for questions about representations or whatever.

I think that reasonable people can take off their technical hats and accept a definition of [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) along the lines of "the study of those things with vertices and edges." No need to mince words.

Comment: I am against attaching the -theory suffix without reasonable cause. Practitioners are bound to be confused by academic distinctions between theory and others, anyway, and telling them "Well, as soon as you use graphs you are doing theory." won't help.

Comment: What's the point of the `-theory` suffix then? Why would I use [tag:graph-theory] and not create the more evidently applicable [tag:graphs] if my question is not about theory, say a question about a graph operation in a compiler (variable interference graphs)? (I've kind of changed my mind as to which tag should be the main tag if we merge. In part because we've got several [tag:graph-theory] questions that could be [tag:graphs], but questions like [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/580) don't look much like graph theory.)

Comment: @Raphael It's sort of a situation similar to the one with "integrity" and "data-integrity": "graph" is a common English word and, even in the context of CS, could reasonably mean a variety of things, not all of which have anything to do with "graph theory". This is less of a problem with other terms, like "tree", which - while having a meaning other than the technical CS one - would (usually) be expected not to come up during discussions of CS. I mean, any chart or plot counts as a "graph", and we can reasonably expect to see plenty of those.

Comment: @Gilles Without reading the description of the tag, new users shouldn't be expected to know whether "graphs" refers to pictures or two the things with nodes and edges, even if they are experienced with both kinds of things. IMHO, that makes "graphs" a bad tag. "graph-theory" is much less objectionable on these grounds, since it typically (in my experience, always) refers to the things with nodes and edges.

Comment: @Patrick87 My point is that if we don't have a [tag:graphs] tag, it's going to be created by someone who won't think that [tag:graph-theory] applies to his question.

Comment: @Gilles While that may be true, we could at least temper that with a good tag wiki, and routine retagging isn't something I'd imagine to be out of the norm on SE sites.

Comment: @Patrick87 A tag wiki can clarify the meaning of an existing tag. Someone who looks for the [tag:graphs] tag and doesn't find it isn't going to be helped by a tag wiki on some other tag. If you're going to be systematically retagging [tag:graphs] into [tag:graph-theory], there's a tool for that: tag synonyms.

Comment: @Gilles, IMHO, that question doesn't need a graph tag at all. It is asking for a data-structure, I don't see how it is related to graphs other that OP not wanting DAGs. I also went over all question tagged graphs and the graph-theory tag would apply to all with the exception of that one. Even if we want to keep the graph tag these questions should be merged to graph-theory.

Comment: @Kaveh Ok, bad example, but I still disagree with removing [tag:graphs] altogether. I'd prefer making [tag:graph-theory] redirect to [tag:graphs] but would be ok with the other direction.

Comment: @Gilles, I not suggesting removing the graphs tag altogether, I don't have an opinion on that. The questions tagged graphs so far are all graph-theory questions and IMO that should be the tag for them.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to summarize discussion from my point of view, since seems this is still an open problem [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

[graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) is not suitable to express a question in graph theory, i.e graph is a general term not scientific name and can be used for charts or even in graphic design, functions, ..., which are not related to computer science. e.g how to draw this graph with tikz is not a graph theory or computer science related but is graph related. Because of three main reasons I want to propose to use tag *synonym* for this:

1. Everyone who works on graph-theory expects to see [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) for questions which are related to algorithms, complexity classes, ... of graphs. e.g there is no [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs)  in CSTheory but there are specific tags like [planar-graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planar-graphs), ... which are more specific and is not comparable with general term *graph* which causes to misinterpreting.
2. Currently all questions that I saw them and tagged by graphs are related to [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) + something or without graph theory just by using other tags. Generally, if some question tagged with [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs), and is not possible to change it to [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) + other tags, means is not computer science problem, it's math, graphic, painting, ... , by writer's understanding and knowledge about CS.SE, we don't have any evidence against this.<sup>1</sup>
3. New people in graph theory or computer scientist who does not work on graph theory related topics, may call [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) as [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs). So for fixing terminology, I would suggest to use tag synonym to change graph/s to [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory).

<sub>1. If anyone thinks there is a question with graph tag and cannot be expressed by other tags, is better to share it here.</sub>

Comment: Your ill-advised editing spree aside, I still don't follow your reasoning. The claim that there "is not [a] scientific name" is ridiculous; the object graph theory studies *is* unequivocally named graph. As a counter-argument to your conclusion (merge the tags), consider [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13542/looking-for-dynamic-network-data-sets) question (there are others). It's clearly not a graph-theory question, but it is as clearly about graphs. How would you tag it?

Comment: Regarding term overloading: this happens all the time and does not bother us at all. Automata, machine, languages, proof, etc -- there are many words that have other meaning in other fields (or the real world). Some even have multiple meaning *inside* CS, e.g. simulation. If that were to disqualify the use of any of these terms, we could hardly talk about anything. But, luckily, the association with "graph" is quite clear (afaik) in computer science, namely nodes and edges. So there is no real problem.

Comment: By the way, it's true that some newcomers use [tag:graphs] wrongly, but that's not not exclusive to this tag; they use tags wrong all the time. Lucky for us, that's easily remedied.

Comment: Saeed: Please [be nice](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: @Raphael, huh? again you talk in a rude manner? Still you didn't learned that here is not a hospital or school? huh?

Comment: @delete aka Saeed: Neither do I see where my comments are rude, nor why you would think it would be acceptable to be rude in a school or hospital. Feel free to contact the community moderators via `team@stackexchange.com`, though. Good luck.

Comment: @Raphael, "ill-advised editing spree aside" is rude. may be is not rude in your opinion, this is just by our personal definition of rudeness, but I think either you didn't think about what you said (childish->school), or you thought about it, and you know what you say (rudeness--> instead of madhouse I wrote hospital to use a little bit polite format). By the way this is totally annoying conversation, and not constructive at all. Just look at your totally nonsense start of first comment, are you series? this is an answer to my post? by the way is not important at all ...

Answer (score -2):

So far, only 7/25 questions tagged with [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) are also tagged with [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory), and 7/14 in the other direction.

I still feel there is a difference. I would not tag questions like [Where to get graphs to test my search algorithms against](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/where-to-get-graphs-to-test-my-search-algorithms-against) with [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory).

For most questions, I can not give a clear criteria of distinction, though. Therefore, I can not speak out against the merge. However, I suggest retaining [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) as the main tag, with [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) the synonym, as [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) appears to be more inclusive.

Comment: Downvotes and no comments? Come on, guys, you are better than that.

Comment: I would tag the particular question you linked to with [graph-theory].  Honestly speaking, if Dijkstra’s algorithm and depth-first search in graphs are not graph theory, I do not know what you call graph theory at all.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: But that question is not about the algorithms but where to get graphs.

Comment: The question asks for data for benchmarking of graph algorithms.  It does not asks for algorithms, but that does not mean that the question is not about graph algorithms.

Comment: @Raphael, I think we should get rid of graphs tag, as other mentioned, this is not appreciated tag in most cases, and as you can see makes confusion.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri This is the first time in over a year that I heard anyone complain about the tag or its use, so I don't quite follow your reasoning. What I see is that one user, you, disagrees with its use. This one data point is of little use, unfortunately. See my other comment; if you want a new discussion, please open a new thread.

Comment: @Raphael, Actually I already read all of comments, and e.g Tshuyoshi Ito's comments to your answers are clarifying that, this is not only me who see some question believes that the question is about graph theory (not general term graphs), but if you think I missed some point I want to hear it. By the way I'll try to prepare more precise answer to your possible questions.

Answer (score -3):

In order to get a clearer voting picture:

Let us keep [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) *and* [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory). We will have to clarify which questions go where, but they describe different things.

Comment: Contrary to your intent, this post is making the voting picture rather obscure.  Kaveh is not proposing to remove [graphs] permanently; he admits that [graphs] may have some legitimate use.  His point is that the questions tagged with [graphs] currently should be retagged with [graph-theory] (which I have not confirmed).

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Kaveh's post is not an answer. If any "voting" is to take place, then amongst the answers. My other and Patrick's answers proposed to get rid one tag but none got a positive score, so I thought there should be an answer to vote on if you want to to keep both.

Comment: “If any "voting" is to take place, then amongst the answers.”  I do not care whether you call it voting or not, but it seems clear to me that currently many people like Kaveh’s proposal that graphs as in graph theory should be tagged as [graph-theory] (no proposal on whether [graphs] tag should be used for something else).

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Not at all. Upvoting the question can also (and should!) mean: "Good question, thanks for bringing that up!" Note that we don't have policy-voting conventions as those on meta.cstheory in place here. Patrick proposes the same solution and only got one vote -- go figure.

Comment: _As I repeatedly said_, Kaveh did not propose anything about possible use of [graphs] tag.  Patrick87’s proposal includes not to use [graphs] as a tag.  They are different.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Well, then *this* answer is equivalent to Kaveh's proposal (w.r.t. tag removal).

Comment: Sigh.  “No proposal” is different from both a proposal to keep and a proposal to remove.  Is this logic that difficult to understand?

Comment: @Raphael, I think when a question clearly proposes a change the votes are not for "Good question, thanks for bringing that up!" Note that this has been discussed already in several places. (but for clarity next time I will explicitly state that the votes on question will be considered votes  for/against proposed change.)

Comment: @Kaveh: I don't think that is a good idea. You should rather post your own answer. Anyway, as it is here we have no way to interpret the voting pattern.

Comment: @Raphael, I disagree. If you search meta you will see that this has come up several times, e.g. [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/136/41). My goal in posting this question wasn't starting a new discussion but to get votes to get it done.

Comment: @Kaveh: I don't see where [tag:graphs] vs [tag:graph-theory] has come up. Can you refer me to the posts? We certainly don't have an established way here about how to put policies/tag changes to a vote. What is the trouble with creating an answer? That would allow people to vote on the question as "I like this question" and would clearly put all possibilities there on the same level. Your way causes unnecessary restrictions (and confusion, as evidenced by this thread).

Comment: @Raphael, the problem is that this is stated as a suggestion and people have already voted on it over a month. I can edit the question and make it explicit and that will give people who would like to retract their votes a chance to do so.

Comment: I think one of a reason that graphs question has low accepted answer rate or fewer answers than other is the kind of tagging, If somebody tag it as graph-theory, then question will be answered normally in good fashion, but if tag it with graph, is not visible to many members search, and they should be lucky to get good answer.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Can you back that claim up by numbers?

Comment: @Raphael, I think is not possible to write a query for beta version, but I'll try tomorrow, but today I changed around 20 question with graph tag, to graph-theory tag, and among this number of questions, (I'm not sure but) I think there was at most 4 question with accepted answer.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri You did that, huh? Be advised that such action is hard to discern from vandalism; you should *always* talk about it on Meta *first*. Besides, mass-edits can have bad effects since they flood the main page, feed readers, etc.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri It's an unwritten rule which everybody abides by (besides you, apparently), even mods. It's also common sense: action should only be taken if the community wants is (with some exceptions that *are* covered by rules); you did not bother to check for that necessary condition. Yes, I could just revert your edits at the risk of starting an "edit war" (requiring me to protect posts and/or ban you temporarily), or I could spend *my* time trying to explain to you what the proper process is. Apparently, that's not a worthwhile use of my time.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri So, if you insist, I'll happily pursue the other road. Or, you know, you could just show some courtesy and open a new discussion (few people will even notice the new comments here) -- if you care enough. If you don't care enough, that's a good indicator that you should never have done an edit.

Comment: And one more, we are going far from original discussion, and this really happened by your totally irrelevant comment, I'd offer you to create a new discussion for this if you want to continue it. (I know I was not polite at discussion, but this is just reflection.)

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Beyond it being common sense, there *are* threads about flooding the front page on [metase]. Regarding who answers, [tag:graph-theory] has twice the followers of [tag:graphs]. I don't understand your purpose with these retags though. Why did you retag those questions? If you see a distinction between the meaning, you need to make it clear and get the community to agree with that distinction on meta first. If there is no distinction, then the tags should be merged, which does not involve editing questions.

Comment: @Gilles, First I don't think talking about this is related to this thread at all, but, sure those are graph-theory questions in my opinion, not graphs question, so I retag them, why you should ask this at all? Also about making distinction, this meta post is enough for this, if you don't have same opinion, another post is just redundant so either merge them or don't ask somebody why retag happened. (Also I don't know what is the point of number of followers? Specially when graph theory has twice as graphs). Seems just you and Raphael are not agree with synonym and this problems are happened.

Comment: @Raphael, I removed my previous comments, because I thought you also going to delete your totally irrelevant comments, this is funny to me, two moderators are talking about something which is not related to the topic of this meta post. At least this is not usual way of discussion for me.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri In this meta thread, the answer that states “graphs and graph-theory are different” doesn't explain how they differ and has a score of -3. If you think the tags are different, write an answer here to explain how you think they differ, and wait for the community's reaction.

Comment: @Gilles, If I didn't answer to your irrelevant [comment](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/188/renaming-tag-graphs-to-graph-theory/724?noredirect=1#comment2285_337), the reason is I think here is not the place for this, not because I cannot answer, and I see someone else upvote it, and is really funny to me, how this can happen. But I would offer to open a new discussion about this, and mention my name explicitly (if you like), then we will see who is right, but for your last comment I wrote my opinion, which is simple conclusion of all discussions in this meta post.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri My comment was (for the most part) about the tags [tag:graphs] and [tag:graph-theory]. Again: if you think they are different, write an answer on the relevant thread, i.e. **here on this very question**.

Comment: @Gilles, Actually I already wrote an answer to the relevant part, just look at answers again.

Comment: @Gilles, I do a redundant post, while I saw a proposal in question, I post another answer! to invite every possible mindless guy to stop talking nonsense. But where is this unwritten and generally accepted rule about my edits? This would be helpful for my future contribution to SE sites. But if there is no rule, I expect your apologize (because of lie, sure I do not expect anything from other one). P.S1: please don't link me to something nonsense, I'll accept every closely related post even on meta stackoverflow. P.S2: don't reply on my old username, use current username if you want to reply.