# Should we merge "graphs" with "graph-theory"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) and [graph-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) seem to cover much of the same ground.

Should we merge them?

Comment: We [discussed this a long time ago](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188/renaming-tag-graphs-to-graph-theory) but didn't come to a solid conclusion.

Comment: I don't think they're synonymous, but people are bad at tagging.

Comment: Can you give an example of the difference?

Comment: Off the top of my head, two types of questions come to mind: 1) [tag:complexity-theory+graphs] such as "Is this problem similar to Vertex Cover also NP-complete?".You'd ask a complexity theorist about that, not a graph theorist. 2) [tag:algorithms+graphs]/[tag:modelling+graphs] -- if it's about modelling a domain problem using graphs and then solving the problem using textbook algorithms, you don't delve into graph theory per se. You're using graphs as a tool. (Of course, this is a question of semantics, and yes, there are overlapping areas of expertise.)

Comment: For me, graph theory is about the structural properties of graphs; a usual theorem is not bothered with algorithms or computational problems.

Comment: Your two examples are both appropriate for the graphs tag. My conclusion is that questions on graph theory just don’t belong here. Questions such as the number of leaves in a complete binary tree (hardly deep graph theory as well; more like discrete math) are more suitable for [math.se]. Perhaps we should add a graph algorithms tag?

Comment: Based on the positive consensus here, I was about to do the merge... but I want to check if we have consensus on the direction of the merge.  We're getting rid of `graph-theory` and keeping `graphs`?  Do I have that right?

Comment: I don't have strong feelings either way. Someone has to make this arbitrary decision, it might as well be you.

Comment: Done!  I have merged them.

Answer (score 5):

+1

I would say *applications of graphs in CS* do not fall in under *graph theory* as a mathematical field (research area), e.g. all the A* questions should be labeled `graph`.

On the other hand, questions regarding graph classes and their complexity (recognition, modification, operations etc.), as well as classical problems like chromatic number etc., should possibly be `graph-theory`.

That said, the distinction is rarely interesting here at cs.sx.

Therefore I vote yes: merge.

Answer (score 2):

+1

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory),

> ... graph theory is the study of graphs, ...

I don't think there is any difference between "graphs" and "the study of graphs".